# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to use dynamicaly created UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a code which creating UIImage dynamically from byte buffer and assigning newly created UIImage to UIImageView.image property:

```
UIImage* UIImageFromDibRect(long w, long h) {
    size_t dataSiz = w * h * 4;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8> data(new uint8[dataSiz]);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data.get(), dataSiz, NULL);


    // set up for CGImage creation
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * w;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(w, h, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // make UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return uiImage;
}

[...]

@interface ScreenViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

[...]

@implementation ScreenViewController

-(void)myMethod {
    UIImage* newImage = UIImageFromDibRect(128, 128);
    self.imageView.image = newImage;
}

@end
```

So, everything works just perfect in emulator and on my iPhone 6s, but it crashes on my iPad 2 here:

```
  0x26bd3182 <+138>: ldr    r0, [r2]
  0x26bd3184 <+140>: blx    0x27507218                ; symbol stub for: -[_UIRemoteViewController(_UIRemoteViewController_AutomaticInvaldiation) autorelease]
> 0x26bd3188 <+144>: mov    r0, r5
  0x26bd318a <+146>: blx    0x27507268                ; symbol stub for: __strlcpy_chk$shim
  0x26bd318e <+150>: mov    r0, r4
```

callstack is empty, i.e. start->main->UIApplicationMain

I use iOS 9.3.3 for both iPhone 6s and iPad2. Target platform is iOS 9.0

btw. UIImage looks ok after creation. And if i replace my **UIImageFromDibRect** with something like this:

```
UIImage* UIImageFromDibRect(long w, long h) {
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(r.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Then everything is working just fine. So, I'm suspicious I'm doing something wrong with **CGImageCreate(...)** or with **CGDataProviderCreateWithData(...)**

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, after you created a `CGColorSpaceRef` and `CGImageRef` retain count increased and ARC will not release by yourself and it may cause a leak, you need a call `CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef)` and `CFRelease(imageRef);` and `CGDataProviderRelease(provider);`

```
UIImage* UIImageFromDibRect(long w, long h) {
    size_t dataSiz = w * h * 4;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8> data(new uint8[dataSiz]);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data.get(), dataSiz, NULL);


    // set up for CGImage creation
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * w;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(w, h, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // make UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CFRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    return uiImage;
}
```

and in your second method `CGContextRef` need release the same `CGContextRelease(context);`

```
UIImage* UIImageFromDibRect(long w, long h) {
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(r.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return image;
}
```

Hope this help fix your crash

Comment: No it doesn't fix my issue. As I said it works just fine with the second method, but it doesn't work with the first one and it only on iPad 2.  And it doesn't look like problem is in resource leakage because it crashes in the beginning. But thanks for tips.

Comment: @Tutankhamen : have you tried `CFRelease(imageRef);` ?

Comment: yes, I did. I've added CFRelease(imageRef) and CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef), but I'm still getting the same exception...

Comment: @Tutankhamen I updated answer and added `CGDataProviderRelease(provider);` try it and try to connect your device and check thought Instruments for detecte any memory leaks

Comment: @Tutankhamen did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue.